How to enable SlidesToScroll in Keen-Slider
This is my Keen-Slider setup in Next Js. I am seeking to add slidesToScroll to my slider setup, but the Keen-Slider document doesn't have nay info on that. How do I achieve this. Thank you.
'use client'

import { useState } from 'react'
import { IoArrowBackSharp, IoArrowForwardSharp } from "react-icons/io5";
import 'keen-slider/keen-slider.min.css'
import { useKeenSlider } from 'keen-slider/react'

function Arrow(props) {
    const disabled = props.disabled ? " arrow--disabled" : ""
    
    return <>
    <button
        className={`${props.left ? "arrow--left" : "arrow--right"} absolute z-50  ${props.left ? "left-3" : "right-3"} top-1/2 -translate-y-2/4 ${disabled ? 'disabled:opacity-0 invisible' : ''} ${disabled}`}
        disabled={disabled}
        onClick={props.onClick}
      >
        <span className="w-[40px] h-[40px] flex items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-white text-center">        
          
        {props.left && (
          <IoArrowBackSharp size={18} />
        )}
        {!props.left && (
          <IoArrowForwardSharp size={18} />
        )}
        </span>
        
      </button>
    </>
  }

  
export default function TestSlider() {

    const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0)
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)

    const [sliderRef, instanceRef] = useKeenSlider({
        initial: 0,
        slideChanged(slider) {
        setCurrentSlide(slider.track.details.rel)
        },
        created() {
        setLoaded(true)
        },
        breakpoints: {
          "(min-width: 400px)": {
            slides: { perView: 2, spacing: 5 },
          },
          "(min-width: 1000px)": {
            slides: { perView: 3, spacing: 10 },
          },
        },
        slidesToScroll: 3
      })



  return (
    <div className="relative">
        <div ref={sliderRef} className="keen-slider">
            <div className="keen-slider__slide bg-neutral-300 aspect-square">1</div>
            <div className="keen-slider__slide bg-neutral-300 aspect-square">2</div>
            <div className="keen-slider__slide bg-neutral-300 aspect-square">3</div>
            <div className="keen-slider__slide bg-neutral-300 aspect-square">4</div>
            <div className="keen-slider__slide bg-neutral-300 aspect-square">5</div>
            <div className="keen-slider__slide bg-neutral-300 aspect-square">6</div>
        </div>

        

    {loaded && instanceRef.current && (
          <>
            <Arrow
              left
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.stopPropagation() || instanceRef.current?.prev(3)
              }
                
              }
              disabled={currentSlide === 0}
            />

            <Arrow
              onClick={(e) =>
                e.stopPropagation() || instanceRef.current?.next(3)
              }
              disabled={
                currentSlide ===
                instanceRef.current.track.details.slides.length - 3
              }
            />
            
          </>
        )}
        
    </div>
  )
}

I tried adding slidesToScroll to my slider setup, but the Keen-Slider document doesn't have nay info on that. How do I achieve this. Thank you.
